# Is generic testing for correct library usage in a wrapper function bad practice?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I hope this question is sufficiently specific for SO. I am in a situation where I wanted to write a wrapper to simplify get-requests often occurring in a project (written in JS) and to generate a single point of change in case of underlying technology-changes. As of now, this wrapper relies on jQuery which I want to change at some point.

The problem I am facing now is how to properly test the wrapper in a good fashion to ensure correctness after the incoming changes.
Things I might wanna test is format of successfully resolved responses or cancelability of long-running requests.

So conceptually speaking to me it seems as I would (a.t.m.) want to test if I am correctly using the underlying library and correctly processing the results given to me.

*Is this conceptually acceptable or does it suggest that the design in itself is lacking?*

(Why do I have this question:

My first approach was to use a mock-server while running the tests to generically intercept requests. So this requires a setup of the mock-server, which in my specific use-case works rather well with "nock" without too much config).
After that, I thought of mocking the wrapper's internal library calls making the actual request.
But to be honest to me this seems rather unsatisfying as this would couple the test-implementation quite tightly with the actual implementation, as I probably would have to rewrite the mocks when switching to another library (also one of the final points made in the worthwhile https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).
As a result, I am asking myself if my approach is per se conceptually broken. )

Hopefully, this was understandable and sufficiently precise.

Comment: As a general rule, you should write your code so that it is *easily testable.*  If you find yourself doing things like writing a lot of mocks or leaning heavily on a mocking library, you should probably rethink your design.  Also, the more logic you push *away* from the UI into its own library, classes or methods, the easier it will be to test and the less you will have to rely on tools like Selenium.

Comment: I try to do that as much as possible. This is actually the first time in this project that I am considering mocking anything. But to be honest, when it comes to tests I still feel very insecure in a lot of aspects. As could be seen in this thread I even struggle to properly pose a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your wrapper hides implementation details from the rest of the application, like in the following diagram: App -> Wrapper -> jQuery.  And now, you are concerned that tests for the wrapper are jQuery specific and will have to be changed if you change that technology.

Well, at least to a large extent this is a situation that is simply unavoidable, because that is in fact the whole purpose of the wrapper: To encapsulate the jQuery dependency.  If you replace jQuery, you will to re-write the wrapper, or, in other words, write a completely different wrapper.

You could make the tests more independent of jQuery by introducing another wrapper, like: App -> wrapper1 -> wrapper2 -> jQuery.  But, if your previous wrapper was a thin layer there will not be much code left to be tested in wrapper1.  And, even if you could split the wrapper into wrapper1 and wrapper2, you could ask the same question: How to test wrapper2 such that the tests would not have to be re-written after the change?  Well, you could try splitting wrapper2: App -> wrapper1 -> wrapper2a -> wrapper2b -> jQuery, and this would go on infinitely...

But, there is possibly a solution for you: You have not shown the code of the wrapper, but it is possible that for the wrapper unit-testing is not the right testing approach.  It is well possible that the wrapper consists mostly of interactions with jQuery.  And, for code that is dominated by interactions with other libraries, it can make sense to simply skip unit-testing and directly go into integration-testing.

Comment: That was actually pretty insightful and logical. Thanks!